# \label inside the \pagecommand inside \includepdfmerge does not seem to work

Tags: cross-referencing, pdfpages

```
\includepdfmerge[
  nup=1x2,
  frame,
  landscape,
  scale=0.8,
  pagecommand={{\chapter{fracture}\section{Theoretical}},{\label{sect:frac-theor}}}]
{icm-model.pdf,1,/Fractal-Fracture-SE.pdf,1}
```

will result in the wrong entry when `\ref{sect:frac-theor}` is subsequenly invoked and does not even point to the correct page.

A similar problem encountered with

```
\includepdf[
  scale=0.8,
  frame,
  page=1,
  pagecommand={{\section{Fluid-Fracture Interaction}},{\label{sect:fluid-fracture}}}]
{c:/Victor/Research/Pdf-Library/Saouma/slowik-dynamic-uplift.pdf}
```

Comment: What's the comma in `pagecommand` for?

Answer (score 2):

The `pagecommand` option doesn't take a list as argument:

```
pagecommand={\chapter{fracture}\section{Theoretical}\label{sect:frac-theor}}
```

Comment: Does `{ }` around `\chapter` and `\section` would localize the internal macros used by `\label`? This would explain why it doesn't work here with them.